# how to make responsive container in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

i want to make my container responsive of image size, but somehow it is not working.

below is the container that I have made-:

```
Container(
              height: size.height * 0.7,
              width: size.width * 0.95,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/vir.gif'),//widget.user.imgUrl),
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12, spreadRadius: 0.5),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

here if the height of image is same as the container then it is good but if the height is less then I am able to see the background that I don't want.

even if I add any information in the container the height remains fixed and doesn't adjust to the
content.

below is another example for this -:

```
 Container(
              height: size.height * 0.2,
              width: size.width * 0.95,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.pink[100],
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    child: Wrap(
                        spacing: 10,
                        children: [

                          Chip(
                            elevation: 5,
                            label: Text('Height'),
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 17,
                            ),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                            deleteIcon: Icon(Icons.height),
                            // labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          ),

                          Chip(
                            elevation: 5,
                            label: Text('Active'),
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 17,
                            ),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          ),

                          Chip(
                            elevation: 5,
                            label: Text('Start Sign'),
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 17,
                            ),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          ),


                        ]
                    ),
                  )



                ],
              ),
            ),
```

here if I add or delete any content then I have to increase or decrease the size manually.
can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to provide a hight or a with. The container adapts to the size of the child.

[Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html):

> Otherwise, the widget has a child but no height, no width, no
> constraints, and no alignment, and the Container passes the
> constraints from the parent to the child and sizes itself to match the
> child.

[Flutter Widget of the week](https://youtu.be/c1xLMaTUWCY?t=34)

Comment: If this answered worked, consider marking these as correct

Comment: but when i remove hight and with that container disappears and there is no error.

Comment: I dont think that the Container disappears, its now just the size of the child (your Image). As far as I understood your question its that what you wanted to achive.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
  MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Hello'),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        child: Image(
          image: NetworkImage(
              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634402-b0eb5e2eebc9? 
               ixid=MXwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb- 
               1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
 ),
 );
 }
```

Comment: Instead of Container, I used Flexible And it worked for me.